# Guarda dato fecha en tiempo real

Tags: sql, visual-studio, mysql-workbench, date

Hay posibilidad de que con **Visual Studio 2017** pueda guardar la fecha en tiempo real? y si es así ¿Con cual la puedo hacer?

Comment: quieres generar el datetime actual en mysql o en qué lenguaje? También te recomiendo editar tu pregunta porque es muy amplia, agrega tu código y especifica el resultado que esperas.

Comment: La pregunta no es totalmente clara. Si quieres tomar la fecha desde tu lenguaje de programación, deberías indicar cuál es, si quieres tomar la fecha con sql sería con `current_timestamp`. Saludos!